# htaccess RewriteRule for optional Parameter?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently trying to implement a REST API. For this, the URL to be called should be in a specific format:

1. `/customer/{customerid}/orders/periods`
2. `/customer/{customerid}/orders/periods/{period}`

I got variants 1 and 2 working with this RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^customer/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/orders/periods/([a-z0-9-]+)?$ api/customer.php?customer_id=$1&period=$2 [L]
```

Now the parameter "year" should be added optionally:
3. `/customer/{customerid}/orders/periods?year={year}`

My approach would be this rule, but that doesn't really work (at least not for variant 2).

```
RewriteRule ^customer/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/orders/periods([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$ api/customer.php?customer_id=$1&year=$2 [L]
```

Does anyone have any ideas? My knowledge of Rewrite Rules is unfortunately somewhat limited.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep your first rule, and add the [`QSA`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag - that stands for Query String Append, and merges the new query string you are creating on your target URL, with the existing one from the originally requested URL.

Comment: With the QSA flag (`[QSA, L]`), I get this entry in the apache error.log:
`.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters`

Comment: There must be no whitespace in there, it needs to be `[QSA,L]`

Comment: Thank you so far.
My rule looks like this now:
`RewriteRule ^customer/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/orders/periods([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?$ api/customer.php?customer_id=$1&period=$2&year=$3 [QSA,L]`

The paramter `periods?year=2022` is recognized, but not the period `periods/2022-02`. Where is my mistake? I guess it's the slash before the date?

Comment: Yes, of course it is - your character class there only allows for letters, digits and a `-`. If there is supposed to be a slash after `periods` - then _write_ a slash after `periods` in your pattern.

Comment: Okay, now I get it. With this it also works.
Thanks again.